Навигация в React Native 0.74
После обновления 22 апреля не получается сделать навигацию между экранами. На данный момент отображается черный экран, а должна отображаться написанная страница. Сначала я изменял код в app/(tab)/_layout.tsx, но позже вернул системный код. На данный момент код в app/(tab)/_layout.tsx выглядит так:
import { Tabs } from 'expo-router';
import React from 'react';

import { TabBarIcon } from '@/components/navigation/TabBarIcon';
import { Colors } from '@/constants/Colors';
import { useColorScheme } from '@/hooks/useColorScheme';

export default function TabLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <Tabs
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[colorScheme ?? 'light'].tint,
        headerShown: false,
      }}>
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="index"
        options={{
          title: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'} color={color} />
          )
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="explore"
        options={{
          title: 'Explore',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'code-slash' : 'code-slash-outline'} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
}

Сама навигация прописана в App.js, который находиться в корне.
App.js
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import { PlayerScreen } from './src/screens/PlayList';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true} >
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={PlayerScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;

Также приложу файл app/(tab)/index.tsx
import { Image, StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';

import App from "../../App";

export default function PlayerScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <App />
    </View>
  );
}

